# CSS html image placement

Tags: html, css

i want to place a image in a very specific place (top right of the NAV bar) and i have done that using postition:relative; (also tried absolute) and moving it accordingly.

when ever i crop the browser it will stay in the white space outside of the div wrapper i have.

so basically my image is not scaling with the div wrapper i have.

can anyone provide some tips? sorry for the noob question.

here is some code.

```
<div id ="Wrapper">
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
  <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>  </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>  </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
  <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
 </ul>
<img src="images/register.jpg" width="50px" height="45px"  id="register"/>
</div><!-- end of css -->
```

Wrapper div is at the bottom.
the css for the "register" id is just positioning coordinates

The nav bar is a template i downloaded.

Comment: show the css you're using as well. the html is useless without it.

Comment: #register{
     position:absolute;
     left:1549;
     bottom:0px;
     }

Comment: how's the positioning defined for the container? is that set for relative, so the 'absolute' stops backtracking there, otherwise it'll backtrack up to the body element and go absolute on that.

Comment: set the container to absolute and it look like it fixed it but it messed with centering. will try and sort that later. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Based on the CSS you provided in your comment, the reason it is doing this is because you are using pixels to set width. If you use a percentage, your image will shift to the screen size. So if you want it at the very right side of your container, try:        `left: 99%;` or change the percentage value to place it where you need it to be.

Comment: ahh thank you, i feel dumb now. also  i cant upvote your answer because i am a low level. ty marc B for your help also.

Answer (score 0):

ok simple try this.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
h3 { 
    word-spacing: 100px;
}
</style>
    </head>
  
 <body>
   <!-- make sure you put it in the heading tag of nav bar right allign-->
<hr>
   <h3>
     <a href="">Example</a>
     <a href="">Example</a>
     <a href="">Example</a>
     <a href="">Example</a>
     <!--Put Image below here-->
     <img src="IMAGE.jpg">
   </h3>  
<hr>
```